# How can I push the camera upwards whenever the player fires their gun and reset the gun's position when they've stop shooting?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, quaternions

So I'm using the FPS Controller prefab from the standard asset and I've attached my script "Camera Push Up Effect" to the main camera(FirstPersonCharacter). Everything is working as it should but the problem that I'm currently having is whenever the player shoot, it doesn't push the camera upwards. What I'm trying to accomplish here is to give some recoil to the player's gun so that it does not stay in one place when the player shoots. I also want to limit the player rotation on the x-axis so that the gun doesn't keep going up forever(the min would be -90 degrees and the max would be 0).

```
using UnityEngine;
using InControl;

public class CameraPushUpEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotateSpeed;
    public float maxRotationX;
    public float minRotationX;
    private Vector3 V3Rotate = Vector3.zero;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        InputDevice device = InputManager.ActiveDevice;

        if(device.RightBumper) // The player is shooting.
        {
            pushCameraUp();
        }
        else if (transform.localRotation.x != 0) // Slerp back to the original unrotated position.
        {
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation, Quaternion.identity, 
                                                       Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);
        }
    }

    private void pushCameraUp()
    {
        V3Rotate.x += rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        float newRotationX = Mathf.Clamp(V3Rotate.x, minRotationX, maxRotationX);
        Quaternion maxRotation = Quaternion.Euler(newRotationX, 0, 0);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation, maxRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: What i've understand is when your player starts shooting, your pushCameraUp() ; function starts working. BUT  you do this in update, so transform.localRotation.x is changed because of the function. And immediately your "else if"  state starts to work. Try to confirm this with commanding out the else if statement. If i am correct, you might need to use coroutines. Or a bool could work

Comment: @EmreE I've commented out the else if and it still doesn't change the X rotation of the weapon(from the inspector, the value remains 0 completely. It doesn't go to some value and then back to 0). Though ideally the else if should only occur after the player has let go of the firing button.

Comment: @EmreE Alright I've gotten my camera to move at this moment but only by adding a transform object of the main camera to this script and attaching this script to my gun object(of course the main camera no longer has this script). My question is why do I need to go the extra step of adding a transform object of the main camera? why does it have to done like this `playerCamera.transform.localRotation = ...` instead of `transform.localRotation = ...`?

Comment: Hmm this is weird. I've not used Unity's fps camera in a while. What i recall is that camera has its own default scripts , at least for cursor movement? Maybe that is blocking what you try to do, but it shouldn't according to what you say. Normally those two should be same. Attaching a script to an object and calling "transform.localRotation"  or attaching that script to another object and giving the referance as "playerCamera". I don't know why yours behave different. Probably we are missing something.@LuisAverhoff

Comment: @EmreE Maybe the culprit has to do with how I'm calculating the rotation on the x -axis.

Comment: @EmreE Good news, I figured out the problem. From various posts that I've read, the issue was with the mouselook script inside The FPSCharacterController prefab(The one in the standard asset). If I disabled the entire FPS controller script(this script uses the mouse look script as a private serializeable field), my code now works. Now I just need to figure how to get the script to work without the mouselook script(this script is also in the standard asset).

Comment: I am glad that worked out. @LuisAverhoff

Answer (score 1):

It would appear it to be that the main culprit is the mouse look script in The First Person Controller script(This script is part of the FPSController prefab). Note the unity that I'm using has mouse look without extending MonoBehaviour and is set as private serializeable. The post in which I found my answer mentioned that it is not possible to rotate your camera(X-Axis) if the mouse look component is attached to the main camera which is clearly not the case(FPSController is the parent of the child FirstPersonCharacter which is tagged as the main camera and FirstPersonCharacter does not have mouse look attached to it). So I simply disabled the First Person Controller script to confirm if this was true and indeed it was.

Here is the link in case others would like to take a look at it as well.

[Help with Recoil for guns](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/205458/help-with-recoil-for-guns.html)